# SD HTTP RESPONSE CODE:200 error with Flurry

Tags: android, flurry

- I am using latest sdk of Flurry Analytics v3.2.2
- But i got below error TOAST when i run my application .

  **SD HTTP RESPONSE CODE:200**
- i don't know from where it comes and how. I goggled it but got nothing.
- **Please tell me if anyone got this type of error using Flurry analytic SDK and how to solve it.**

Comment: Thnx for telling  .But why this msg appear every time when i run the App ?.

Comment: Seeing the same thing in my Android app running under Titanium.

Comment: Not sure why this question keeps getting downvoted. This question doesn't reflect someone who doesn't understand what an http 200 message means. It seems to be a real, new, problem with the latest Flurry library where an Android Toast popup appears in the app UI from the Flurry library which should be silent!

Comment: why downvoted? I face the same problem as I did not know which of the libraries is throwing this toast. Upvoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This Toast appear when you have enable logs on the version 3.2.2 :

```
        FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
        FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(android.util.Log.VERBOSE);
```

So, don't worry, when you are in release, just disable the logs of flurry.

Comment: My problem is that there is nothing else going on when in debug mode. I set up flurry with proper KEY, added package name on Flurry's site. Start the app, and all I get are the lines:

FlurryAgent(26808): Attempting to persist AdLogs
FlurryAgent(26808): Attempting to persist FreqCap
FlurrySession(26808): Session ended

No logs on flurry no reports of defined events on LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Flurry support and they gave me the 3.2.0 library to try (vs the current release version of 3.2.2), and the Android Toast message no longer appears at startup. I'll update this when it's completely resolved, but for now I'm going to do more testing with the older library.

Comment: Thanx. But i dont want to replace SDK to lower version.